# Handling page refresh in angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

When ever I reload/refresh the page, the state routes back to root page. When I checked the value of `$state.current` after reload it is empty.

currentState:

```
Object {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
```

States:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngCookies','ngResource','ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        data: {
            required: false
        }
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",
        data: {
            required: true
        }
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})

.run(["$rootScope", "$state", "$location", "authService", "$cookies", "$sessionStorage", function ($rootScope, $state, $location, authService, $cookies, $sessionStorage) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    console.log("currentState: ", $state.current);
    console.log("toState is:", toState);

    if (toState.data.required && !$sessionStorage.authuserid) {
        alert("state not authenticated");
        e.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
});
}]);
```

why the value of current state becomes empty on refresh?

Comment: When page loads there is no `current` until after the first change but you are checking before the first change

Comment: @charlietfl I know that but after successful login it routes to dashboard page and when I refresh the page it routes back to login page as the `$state.current` value is empty

Comment: @charlietfl So many are facing the same problem. Refer to this page: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1985

Comment: My suggestion is use a `resolve` on parent state for all areas that need login. Then children of that state can't be accessed if parent resolve is rejected

Comment: @charlietfl I don't think that will solve the issue. It is not a login problem here. The states data is empty just like session data when page is closed

Comment: It would replace `'$stateChangeStart'` code you have. Really not clear how you are trying to use `$state.current`